# undefined reference to 'pcap_......'

Tags: compiler-errors, makefile, pcap, undefined-reference

Im working under Ubuntu 14.04.2
I am trying to install the software called "[VideoSnarf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ucsniff/files/videosnarf/videosnarf-0.63.tar.gz/download)"
Because this software requires pcap, I type

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

Then I type

```
./configure
make && make install
```

but I get an error saying

```
videosnarf.o: IN function 'mediasnarfStart':
videosnarf-0.62/src/videosnarf.c:74 undefined reference to 'pcap_open_offline'
videosnarf-0.62/src/videosnarf.c:88 undefined reference to 'pcap_datalink'
videosnarf-0.62/src/videosnarf.c:101 undefined reference to 'pcap_compile'
videosnarf-0.62/src/videosnarf.c:105 undefined reference to 'pcap_setfilter'
videosnarf-0.62/src/videosnarf.c:110 undefined reference to 'pcap_loop'
videosnarf-0.62/src/videosnarf.c:79 undefined reference to 'pcap_open_live'
videosnarf-0.62/src/videosnarf.c:102 undefined reference to 'pcap_open_geterr'
videosnarf-0.62/src/videosnarf.c:106 undefined reference to 'pcap_open_geterr'
```

Is this caused by the order of library in Makefile?
If it is how do I fix it? I am not familiar to Makefile

Comment: What's the linking command that was run that generated that output? That's going to be either a missing argument or an argument order problem.

Comment: g++  -g -O2   -o videosnarf -lpcap main.o stream.o videosnarf.o h264rtp.o g722_decode.o g726_decoder.o g729_decoder.o g723_decoder.o ../codec-lib/libG729a.a ../codec-lib/libG7231.a ../codec-lib/libG726.a

Comment: Yeah, that's an argument order problem. The `-lpcap` argument needs to be *after* the object files that use the `pcap` symbols for it to work.

Comment: g++ -g -O2 -o videosnarf main.o stream.o videosnarf.o h264rtp.o g722_decode.o g726_decoder.o g729_decoder.o g723_decoder.o -lpcap ../codec-lib/libG729a.a ../codec-lib/libG7231.a ../codec-lib/libG726.a    I just typed this command but this command produces error "No such file or directory". Do I need to edit Makefile?

Comment: Did you run that from the correct directory? You will need to edit some Makefile (or Makefile.in/Makefile.am as appropriate) if you want this to happen correctly on its own. You should probably report this to the ucsniff authors.

Comment: I downloaded debian file instead and used Ubuntu software center to open and compile. Somehow it worked now.... Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Last time I saw this I had to add `-lpcap` when compiling. You may need to add this cflag in the Make file.